# When I try to create new account, configuration error or permission error occur

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user

I am trying to create new account in Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo adduser --force-badname "jenkins"

Adding user `jenkins' ...

Adding new group `jenkins' (1001) ...

configuration error - unknown item 'PASS_MIN_LEN' (notify administrator)

Adding new user `jenkins' (1001) with group `jenkins' ...

configuration error - unknown item 'PASS_MIN_LEN' (notify administrator)

Creating home directory `/home/jenkins' ...

Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...

passwd: Permission denied
passwd: password unchanged
```

I commented out the PASS_MIN_LEN item in /etc/login.defs, but the following errors still occur:

```
passwd: Permission denied
passwd: password unchanged
```

How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: http://www.unixresources.net/linux/lf/24/archive/00/00/18/05/180545.html

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I already applied your solution. but I still get permission denied error.

Comment: Check your system logs and see if they contain additional error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Look under `/etc/security/*`. The files under there control the limits imposed by PAM now. There are notes about this move in the `/etc/pam.d` files, specifically the `login` file.